# US/UK/CA Postal Code validation in PHP

Tags: php, zipcode, postal-code

Im not so good with regex. Im looking to add a validation function that will return true/false if the string entered into it is a valid US, UK, or CA zip/postal code.

US: NNNNN
CA: LNL NLN
UK: Lots of combinations

L = letter, N = Number

There are individual functions for US, and Canada, but I failed to come up with a single unified function to do this.

Comment: Do you want to do a *real* check for the UK (i.e. find only existing postcodes)? Or would a pattern be enough?

Comment: Same question for US ... 66666 matches the pattern but is not a valid postal code. Then there's the `NNNNN-NNNN` "ZIP+4" form too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`Zend_Validate_Postcode`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.set.html) from the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/):

> Zend_Validate_PostCode allows you to
>   determine if a given value is a valid
>   postal code. Postal codes are specific
>   to cities, and in some locales termed
>   ZIP codes.
>
> Zend_Validate_PostCode
>   knows more than 160 different postal
>   code formates. To select the correct
>   format there are 2 ways. You can
>   either use a fully qualified locale or
>   you can set your own format manually.

I guess you could either look at the source, or use it as a stand-alone component. It may have dependencies within the ZF, but you will certainly not need to use the entire framework just for that component. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

My solution would be to go for three separate regexes using logical `OR` operators:

```
if (
    preg_match('/^\d{5}(?:\-\d{4})?$/i', $code, $matches) OR
    preg_match('/^[a-z]\d[a-z] ?\d[a-z]\d$/i', $code, $matches) OR
    preg_match('/^[a-z]{1,2}\d{1,2} ?\d[a-z]{2}$/i', $code, $matches)
) {
    // deal with $matches here
}
```

Note that this works because PHP uses short-circuit logic.  Once one test has passed, the others are ignored so `$matches` won't be overridden.